# API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API. Error on Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, api, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I need google map on my flutter android application.
I did everything correctly. Enabled All Google Map API, Created Credentials, restricted using SHA-1 and everything. But when I compile the code and install on device. I am getting

> API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API.

Pubspec

[image]

AndroidManifest

[image]

API Key

[image]

Error message

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from [posting images of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post,asking%20a%20question%3F). Instead, please provide a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community could help you.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? Dealing with similar issue with Flutter and Web

Comment: Yes, the system was designed to use same keys. I thought we should create new keys for each application but no need to use same key.